# Problem with synching customers with MailChimp through API v.3: Customer Was Not Saved

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to synchronize customer entities of an online store with MailChimp e-commerce service. Most of them synched successfully, but some others failed. The response of API is as below:

```
{"status_code":400,"operation_id":"855","response":"{\"type\":\"http:\/\/developer.mailchimp.com\/documentation\/mailchimp\/guides\/error-glossary\/\",\"title\":\"Customer Was Not Saved\",\"status\":400,\"detail\":\"Customer could not be imported to the list associated with this store.\",\"instance\":\"\"}"}
```

I couldn't find any explanation for this error in official documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've posted a ticket in the MailChimp support system about my problem. This is their answer, just for the information of any other person facing this issue:

1. The email address is blacklisted from signing up
2. The email address is invalid
3. The email address is not UTF-8 encoded
4. The address was added to the list too many times in a short period of time